# How to cancel create an cativity action on ms crm 4.0?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-4

i have a plugin for an activity.

on pre create i check few conditions and if i get true so i throw OperationCanceledException for stop the create execution.

but the record was saved, why? how do i can to cancel the creation? also tried to throw InvalidPluginExecutionException, but it's stil executed..

the code:

```
 public void Execute(IPluginExecutionContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (context.MessageName)
            {
                case "Create":
                    if (context.Stage == MessageProcessingStage.BeforeMainOperationOutsideTransaction)
                    {
                        bool shouldnotcreateactivity = Create(context, service);

                        if (shouldnotcreateactivity)
                            throw new OperationCanceledException();
                    }
                    if (context.OutputParameters.Properties.Contains("id"))
                    {
                        //continue...
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException cancled)
        {
        }
        catch (InvalidPluginExecutionException invalid)
        {
        }
        catch (SoapException ex)
        {
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are doing something wrong. You should probably post some of your code realting to the pre-checking and saving of the activity

You should have some logic like the following...

```
if(ValidateActivity()){
    CreateAndSaveActivity();
}
else
    throw execption;
```

Comment: Add what is in your Create method? Are you certain this is returning the value you want? and the exception is indeed being thrown?

Comment: The Create method  is for check if should i cancel the execution of an activity. yes i debug that and the method is return true if should i to cancel that.. and the exception is thrown, but i saw that it's continue to the post create plugin..

Comment: it's resolved - by edited as  catch (OperationCanceledException cancled)
            {
                throw;
            }